# Python - pandas, group by and max count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need the most similar (max count) from column cluster-1 from column cluster-2.

> Input - data

[image: Input data]

> Output - data

[image: output]

I use the command: **df.groupby(['cluster-1','cluster-2'])['cluster-2'].count()** this command will give me count per occurrence in the column cluster-2. I need advice on how to proceed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) because by default sorted values, so possible convert `MultiIndex` to `DataFrame` by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) and then remove duplicates by `cluster-1` in [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['cluster-1'])['cluster-2']
         .value_counts()
         .index
         .to_frame(index=False)
         .drop_duplicates('cluster-1'))
```

Comment: Can you advise me more with other output? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrikNovotný - Is possible create sample data like text?

Comment: I edited the question, there is also output2. I would also need this output, thank you.